# Get-SPLogEvent returns nothing

Tags: 2013, powershell, administration, uls

I use Get-SPLogEvent PowerShell command in order to retrieve ULS logs by following below link.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ie/library/ff607589.aspx

However, it returns nothing; neither error message nor result. When I press enter cursor moves to next line and ready for next command.

And this is the command which I tried to run.

```
Get-SPLogEvent -StartTime "04/08/2016 11:00" -EndTime "04/08/2016 13:00" | Out-GridView
```

What is wrong with PowerShell or SharePoint?

Comment: it works fine for me. Have you tried without Out-GridView ? Get-SPLogEvent -StartTime "04/08/2016 11:00" -EndTime "04/08/2016 13:00"

Comment: none of the examples in the https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ie/library/ff607589.aspx page are working. I also tried with different dates.

Comment: is the ULS log in its folder?

Comment: Yes, I expect at least an error message. but nothing happens,

Comment: what about the ulviewer https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44020 ?